# Best practices for Conditional Flow with Project Reactor

Tags: java, web, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working with **spring webflux** and **project reactor** building an API with 2 layers: **controller** and **service**. All the **3 endpoints** that my API have send and return a request/response wrapped with ***Mono.*** In the service layer I have two classes: the first one calls several webclients with ***Mono*** responses and the second one is the class integration for those calls. I have been struggling with building "pipeline" of Mono calls because the business flow dictate that I need to call webclient 1, do some validation, use its response and call webclient 2, perform validation call webclient 3 if passes otherwhise webclient 4 and so on... I have tried with flatmap but its not natural for me create a conditional flow with Mono like this :

[Business Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XCqf.png)

As you can see on the diagram i'ts not a easy way for me to implement the conditional flow of reactive web client calls.
There is a best practice to do this whitout calling a nested calls of flatmaps, and maps and with good readability of my code?

Answer (score 2):

You may place conditional statements to `flatMap` and use switchIfEmpty to return other publisher. A short example:

```
myService.executeWc1() // returns Mono
        .flatMap(result -> myService.executeWc2(result))
        .flatMap(result -> validator.validate(result))
        .handle((result, sink) -> {
            if (result) { // validation is passed
                sink.success(true);
            }
            sink.success();
        })
        .flatMap(result -> myService.doSomeWork()
                .flatMap(r -> myService.executeWc3())
                .flatMap(r -> myService.doSomeWorkAgain())
                .flatMap(r -> myService.executeWc4()))
        .switchIfEmpty(myService.executeWc4())
```

and so on...